# Java code snippet not working as expected: Using ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Currently `newResult` is getting values: `[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]`

I am trying to get `[[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]`
Basically, as a base case, in result, I am putting `[[0], [1]]`
and then I am trying to add elements to it, thru copying result in `newResult` twice and then appending 0 in first half and appending 1 in second half.

I am using `clone()` also, but not able to resolve issue

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListNestedTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> newResult = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> zero = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        zero.add(0);
        ArrayList<Integer> one = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        one.add(0);
        result.add(zero);
        result.add(one);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tmp1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tmp2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        tmp1 = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>) result.clone();
        tmp2 = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>) result.clone();
        newResult.addAll(tmp1);
        newResult.addAll(tmp2);
        newResult.get(0).add(0);
        newResult.get(1).add(0);
        newResult.get(2).add(1);
        newResult.get(3).add(1);
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use the abstract type, and inferred type, when declaring a list, ie `List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();`. Never use `clone()`; use the copy constructor `List<List<Integer>> tmp1 = new ArrayList<>(result);` to copy a list (note that this is a shallow copy). You really need to debug your code; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173

Comment: I have not fully analyzed your code but do you realize the clone does not do a deep clone.  So for the nested lists, the contained ones will be the same objects.  You should just copy them.

Comment: I think you're going about this the hard way. Consider iterating from 0 to 3, converting that number to binary, then converting the binary digits to elements in a list, then collection those lists (you can do the entire task in 1 line).

Comment: @Bohemian : Yes, the alternative suggested seems interesting and more straightward. Will try it.

Comment: I believe that if you indent your code properly, more people will be interested in analysing it. Your IDE can do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, describe more briefly your task. It looks like you make too many actions. For example: is it absolutly necessary to make a clone?

Thanks to [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) comment. I have changed double curly braces for initializer `new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(0);}}` to `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0))` because [it is strongly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java/27521360#27521360).

Simple solusion could be this one:

```
    List<List<Integer>> newResult = new ArrayList<>();
    newResult.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0)));
    newResult.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1)));
    newResult.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0)));
    newResult.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1)));

    newResult.get(0).add(0);
    newResult.get(1).add(0);
    newResult.get(2).add(1);
    newResult.get(3).add(1);

    System.out.println(newResult);
```